# Filter Timer for Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am looking for a means, programmatically or otherwise, to run a Thunderbird message filter every X number of minutes.  Thunderbird has a built-in option to run a filter on the Inbox every 10 minutes.  But This is not adjustable.  I am looking for a way to run any specified message filter every 1 minute.

I've searched around and unfortunately (for me) this does not seem to be an issue others are trying to solve.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

(And in the mean time, I will RTFM Thunderbird to see if there is a way I can solve this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird / Settings / Advanced / show all

mail.server.default.periodicFilterRateMinutes    5  minutes